# Correct usage of ddrescue

Tags: hard-drive, ddrescue

I have a 80gb Maxtor IDE HDD that suddendly fail.
I start using `ddrescue` from systemrescuecd.
the cose i use is:

```
ddrescue -d /dev/sdc image.dd logfile.log
```

it's been 2 days that it's running. it rescue the 99.94% of the data but now its simply slow, really slow at the scraping phase.

I didn't understand well the parameters (so i can make it faster).

1. the `-n` option, jump the scraping phase? so he simply stop to recover
   data from the bad sector? and I can use the image file as is?
2. can I stop the process and resume it with the `-n` parameter?
3. what is the `-reverse` parameter? and how to use it? I have had to use it on the same image that is building now on forward?

basicly on 80gb, just
thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. option `-n` tell to skip scraping phase to reduce time of rescue.
2. you can interrupt the rescue at any time and resume it later at the same point if you using mapfile (you named it as logfile.log).
3. `--reverse` simply reverse the direction of all passes (copying, trimming, scraping and retrying)

Try to read [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html):  Don't just read that options you are interesting, but the whole documentation

If I would be on your place(attempt to rescue failing HDD) I will first use some dedicated software(such as Victoria or mhdd. AFAIK both of them included in hiren's bootcd ) that talk directly to HDD's controller and force firmware of HDD to remap sectors(replace failing sectors with a spare ones).